# How parseInt() method return an integer

Tags: javascript, parseint

I read a post about parseInt() method of JavaScript from [w3Scools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp) site. Under "definition and usage" section it says,

> The parseInt() function parses a string and returns an integer

In [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures) site it says there are only 6 types of primitive types, but integer is not one of them.

I'm confused with this. If integer is not a type in JavaScript how a method return an integer. Can someone explain this.

Comment: There is a difference between what it is and what its representation is

Comment: It returns a Number type that is an Integer. (or NaN)

Comment: yes it has numbers not integers

Comment: You really want to understand it? Then read this: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-parseint-string-radix

Comment: @e11438 Please read the description of number type; use the same MDN URL, which you given

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation that you read is misleading. The `parseInt` method returns a number, but it returns a number without anything after the decimal point.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer

Answer (score 0):

`parseInt` returns a value that is in the set of integers.  The primitive type `Number` is the data type that represents both integers and floating point numbers in JavaScript.

There is an important distinction between the type of number, and the way it is represented.